# SQL Query on DBC type file format from C# code. Date comparison in WHERE clause is not working

Tags: c#, sql, date, ms-access, where-clause

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new(@"Provider=VFPOLEDB;Data Source=C:\PATIENTS.DBC;Mode=Read;Collating Sequence=machine"))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT admissions.disDate FROM patadmissions WHERE (((admissions.disDate)=#12/30/1899#)) ", conn))
    {
        OleDbDataReader reader;
        conn.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.Read() == false)
        {
            throw new Exception("There is no category with that name");
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(reader);

        int numRows = dt.Rows.Count;

        Console.WriteLine("The number of records are: " + numRows);
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

When I execute this code, I get an error at line

```
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

Error is:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Missing operand.'

This SQL query works perfectly in MS ACCESS.

Comment: Do you mean to have # around your date in your SQL query?

Comment: Try : "SELECT " + admissions.disDate +  " FROM patadmissions WHERE (((" + admissions.disDate + ")=#12/30/1899#)) "

Comment: I think the problem is that the statement is valid for ms-access, but you are connecting to your db using vfpoledb. I don’t think FoxPro accepts `#` as delimiter.

Comment: Is this a FoxPro db, why the Access tag? Try apostrophe instead # character.